# How to view data from database as rest api in asp.new web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webapi, asp.net-apicontroller

I have created an ASP.NET Web API and coded a function to get data from a database like this:

```
public string Get()
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM employee", con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
    }
    else
    {
        return "No Data Found ...";
    }
}
```

I get the data like this: this XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
[ { "emp_id": 1, "frist_name": "Dived", "last_name": "Mark",
  { "emp_id": 2, "frist_name": "Anna", "last_name": "Smith" } ]
</string>
```

How can I view data like rest api like this?

```
{
  list: [
         {
          "emp_id":1,
          "frist_name":"Dived",
          "last_name":"Mark"
         },
         {
          "emp_id":2,
          "frist_name":"Anna",
          "last_name":"Smith"
         },
        ],
  count: 2,
  success: true
}
```

Comment: `frist_name` is probably a typo and should be `first_name` instead